# How exactly do you reintegrate a branch into a parent branch using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

So, I had this problem again and decided to hear from the experts(please only those who know what they are talking of please).

I created a branch(DUMMY-BRANCH) from another branch(called UAT_BRANCH and this main is sort of a main branch for test releases). I made changes in DUMMY-BRANCH and tested those changes until I was satisfied with those changes. Then it came time to merge my changes back to the main branch, in this case UAT_BRANCH, and I went ahead and opened up TortoiseSVN to get this done.  I opened up the online manual at [MERGE TWO DIFFERENT TREES](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html) , and proceeded to yet again try my hand at getting this merging thing right. I specified UAT_BRANCH as the FROM(start URL) and DUMMY-BRANCH as the TO(End URL). I tested the merge  and then did the actual merge in the end. When I refreshed UAT_BRANCH and checked to see if the changes in my branch had been re-integrated, I found it was not. Now subsequent attempts at switching the FROM AND TO urls yielded no result, probably cause the damage has been done or something(I figure reintegration had already taken place and there was no undoing it).

What I would like is some clear explanation of what I did wrong in this case please and how to actually do a merge in SVN or in fact tortoiseSVN. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KenWhite - not sure if it makes a difference but the answer in your link assumes that the working directory is the trunk. The question above seems not to be the case.

Comment: @Kobojunkie - I don't know if your question is a duplicate. However I must agree with you. The merge process for Tortoise SVN seems a bit un-natural, and I always have to look at the docs every time I do it.

Comment: My question is not a duplicate. I followed the online manual for TortoiseSVN, after creating a branch from another branch, and tried to merge my branch into the original branch(Note I was not working directly from the UAT-branch).

Comment: Can anyone out there please help? I need  to master TortoiseSVN in a short-time. :)

Comment: @KenWhite you clearly didn't actually follow the link provided.  The answer to the question is actually a good description of branching and makes sense whether you're actually merging to the trunk or another branch, and follows what TortoiseSVN provides for options quite well.  The key thing is that you don't want to "Merge Tow Branches" (it seems counter intuitive, but that's what they say) and actually want "Merge a range of revisions".

Comment: @mtaexan: You clearly didn't look at the date of this post (or my comment) before commenting. :-) A 9 month old comment indicating a possible duplicate on a post that is still open clearly indicates no one else agreed. Thanks, though. The comment is obsolete, clearly; I'll clean up the clutter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point - as you did several intents, also switching **from** and **to** - it is impossible to be certain of what exactly happened and what is the situation now. Still, I would suggest the following (as doing it via TortoiseSVN UI).

When you want to reintegrate a branch, you have to :

1. Update the local copy of Trunk (UAT_BRANCH in your case) and commit all the changes, if any.
2. Port the changes ***from the Trunk to the branch***. You do this by choosing the option "Merge a range of revisions" and then select the Trunk as **"URL to merge from"**. For the **"Revision range to merge"** select the branch creation revision number as the initial in the range and the HEAD revision number as final (or you can leave this box empty for the same result). Try with "Test merge" and, if everything ok, merge it. What you have now is a local copy of branch updated with all the revisions from the Trunk. (It seems that you perhaps did so in your first intent, in case that you did it with "Merge a range of revisions").
3. If everything went well in the previous step, you are ready to ***merge the branch with the Trunk***. Now select the folder of your local copy of Trunk and choose from the *Merge* menu "Reintegrate a branch", then for **"From URL"** select the branch. For **"Working copy"** should appear the folder of your local copy of Trunk. Again, test merge it before running the real merge. Now you have a local copy of Trunk updated with branch. If you commit it, you will take all the changes to the repo.

Perhaps, after all your tries, you are lucky enough to still have a local copy of branch (DUMMY-BRANCH) updated with Trunk revisions. If it is true, follow with the step 3. If you are not sure, try to revert the changes (be carefull to not lose the work in the branch, make a copy for just in case) and go through all the process.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

Seems that you try to complete wrong scenario by "Merge two different trees". You need "Reintegrate a branch" scenario, described in the same online manual you refer to.
Please note that you have to perform merge operation on UAT_BRANCH working copy and use DUMMY-BRANCH as 'From URL'. Also, your version of Svn must support merge tracking. Make sure that your working copy of UAT_BRANCH is up to date before merge, then perform 'Reintegrate a branch' merge on it, then commit changes.